# Logging data received to a txt file

Tags: java, logging, log4j, filewriter

I want to log data to a txt file, i.e. I will receive the data from the com port and then write it to the text file. Does this qualify as logging? or is logging referring to error logging? If the first case is true I guess I am supposed to use log4j as I have read that this is the standard for logging? However if this is not the case is it then ok to use FileWriter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `java.util.logging.Logger`. Use the following steps:

1. At startup, create a `Logger` with `Logger.getLogger(name)` (you define whatever logging name you want to use for your system).
2. Decide where you want the logs to go by using `Logger.addHandler`. For example, if you want to output the logs to a file, use `java.util.logging.FileHandler`.
3. Everywhere you want to log something, use `Logger.getLogger(name).log()`.

That's it! The FileHandler will write your text file automatically. If you want to put the logs somewhere else (for example, a database), add a different Handler.

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing something similar using the Rxtxcomm library.
There is no problem using log4j to log the data incoming from the serial port.

In fact, logging doesn't necessary mean "error logging". For example, if you are trying to find out in which configuration a bug in your program appears, you can use your program to log as much information as possible.
In my case, I logged the use of events like the detection of the Carrier Detect signal.